# Image from Camera/Camera Roll only uploading to Firebase once

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

**Edit**
I am making an app using Swift and using Firebase. In the app I utilize the camera as well as the camera roll.

The user is required to fill in 2 textfields in order to enable the next button but it is optional to take or use a picture.

I have tested my app with just filling out the required textfields and creating an account and it works fine, but if I add the image it only works the first time.

This is the delegate method code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
      print(editedImage)
      selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
      print(originalImage)
      selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
    }
    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
      accountImageView.image = selectedImage
    }
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The code I am using to write to Firebase Database and Storage is thus

```
...
let account = ref.child("accounts").childByAutoId()
...
if selectedImageFromPicker != nil {

  if let tempData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImageFromPicker!) {
    storageRef.put(tempData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        return
      }

      self.accountMetadata = metadata?.downloadURL()

      if let tAccountName = self.accountName,
        let tAccountEmail = self.accountEmail,
        let tProfileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

        account.setValue(["accountName": tAccountName,
                          "accountEmail": tAccountEmail,
                          "accountImage": tProfileImageUrl,
                          "accountHasImage": true])
      }
      print(metadata!)
    }
  }
} else {

  if let tAccountName = accountName,
    let tAccountEmail = accountEmail {
    account.setValue(["accountName": tAccountName,
                      "accountEmail": tAccountEmail,
                      "accountImage": "",
                      "accountHasImage": false])
  }
}
ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("accounts").child(account.key).setValue(true)
}
```

Currently, what is happening is that when I launch the app, and try to add an account and use the camera/camera roll the first time and tap the submit button it will work fine. It creates the account node and then a reference to that account node in the users node as well as the image in the storage. However, if I try to add a 2nd account with another picture, it does not add the account node or the image in storage, BUT it does create the reference to the account node in the user node (which is the a problem).

This is a problem because in my UICollectionView when I try to pull all of the accounts, it sees that it has a reference to a child and then tries to pull that child, and since that child isn't actually there I get a crash.

I am not sure if I am using the proper Firebase terminology. My previous app is similar in structure to this app, so I know it should work. The only thing I have changed is adding the camera ability and Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always creating a reference to the account in the user node because of this instruction.

```
ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("accounts").child(account.key).setValue(true)
```

You have nested conditions and whatever `selectedImageFromPicker == nil` or not, you can be in a state where no code is executed, and you finally ends with an account under the user node.

Try moving account creation in the user node at the same level of adding a node to accounts reference.

```
...
let account = ref.child("accounts").childByAutoId()
...
if selectedImageFromPicker != nil {

  if let tempData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImageFromPicker!) {
    storageRef.put(tempData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        return
      }

      self.accountMetadata = metadata?.downloadURL()

      if let tAccountName = self.accountName,
         let tAccountEmail = self.accountEmail,
         let tProfileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

        account.setValue(["accountName": tAccountName,
                        "accountEmail": tAccountEmail,
                        "accountImage": tProfileImageUrl,
                        "accountHasImage": true])
>>>    ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("accounts").child(account.key).setValue(true)
      }
      print(metadata!)
    }
  }
} else {
  if let tAccountName = accountName,
     let tAccountEmail = accountEmail {

    account.setValue(["accountName": tAccountName,
                      "accountEmail": tAccountEmail,
                      "accountImage": "",
                      "accountHasImage": false])
>>> ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).child("accounts").child(account.key).setValue(true)
    }
  }
}
```